# Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

Tags: typescript

How to handle this error here? Can I limit the recursion depth, or just tell TS that it's ok?

```
export type StateUnion<T> = T extends { states: Record<infer K, any> }
  ? K | StateUnion<T['states'][K]>
  : never;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMCGNgFUB2AlhPgDwAqAfHALxzlyg74AmAznAN5xtY5sAuOACVgAY2gtShfADNgUOAGkANHEz5E1AL4AoOHAD8yuAB90fPERIUA2gHJe2YG3sBdW0reV9cIfmAANwUAbl1w0EhYOBkcKFlMMVQAYRJZQgBzLl8nfkMhUQkoKV4oGQy1VLlMyjC9XUjoeFkAV3wxGGJ8OABbRIALGWAKRhBmdjgq9IzKAAoJaoyhcgBKbIMoYBgWqG7OXwMYKA02Qk6SFV9tMN9W9vPuo5Ozrtnc4CEMZwIuiko1-YGAwLXg8SwYRR0d5hAx6PRAA)

Comment: Is there any reason to use the type `any` instead of `unknown`? It does not raise any error using `unknown`

Comment: No reason, that works fine. If you would like to write it up - I'll accept the answer.

Comment: If you want to write a depth limiter you can do so [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3vnkN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) like `StateUnion` and apply it to a type that is itself recursive, like `Config`, you can easily get into situations where the compiler complains about recursion depth.  Sometimes you can tweak one or both of your definitions to sidestep the problem, but those approaches tend to be trial-and-error (at least in my experience).

One approach you might try is to give a explicit depth limiting mechanism to your recursive conditional type, picking a reasonable default maximum depth but allowing users to change it.  For your `StateUnion` it could look like this:

```
type StateUnion<T, D extends number = 8, A extends any[] = []> =
  A['length'] extends D ? never : (
    T extends { states: Record<infer K, any> }
    ? K | StateUnion<T['states'][K], D, [0, ...A]>
    : never);
```

Here the intended use is `StateUnion<T, D>` where `D` is a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to the desired max depth.  If you write `StateUnion<T>` without specifying `D` then the max depth is `8` (but you can change that).

Unfortunately TypeScript (as of v5.1) doesn't know how to do math at the type level directly, so I can't easily say something like `StateUnion<T['states'][K], D-1>`.  Instead I resort to using [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) which have a known numeric literal `length` property, and [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to manipulate these types.  So instead of the normal "if depth is 0 then bail out, otherwise reduce depth by 1 and recurse", I have to say something like "if the length of this array is the same as the maximum depth then bail out, otherwise append an element to the array and recurse".  So I have that accumulator array `A` in there, and we are checking `A["length"]` and passing in `[0, ...A]` as the new `A`.

Let's test it:

```
interface Test {
  states: { a: { states: { b: { states: { c: {
    states: { d: { states: { e: Test } } } 
  } } } } } }
}

type SU2 = StateUnion<Test, 2>
//type SU2 = "a" | "b"
type SU4 = StateUnion<Test, 4>
//type SU4 = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"
type SU8 = StateUnion<Test> // defaults to 8
// type SU8 = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e"
```

That works as expected, and if I make that change then your original code with `StateUnion<Config>` (or `StateUnion<T>` where `T extends Config`) compiles without error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKMCGNgFUB2AlhPgDwAqANHACJyg74AmAznPgK4C2ARsFHAC8cABzUAgvRCNWcTPkQBtALpC4KgHxCAUHDjjFAcgA2wfAHMYAC0OqGZ2XQD87YADd+cAFxwAFLr04cikZNgBvOBYsHBYfACVgAGNoJlJCfAAzTwBpanlELQBfAL0XbLgAH3RovCISCiMo7GAWW0Vs5WoaakUABmoAOiHxZQ0S71cPKABKAG5tBdBIWDh0nCgMzETUAGESDMJzODCAppineKSU0iiodPNqPczDjXni7SXoeAyOfESYYj4OBcLZWdLACghBxsJ4HcwaXzJZ7mHzkabHAJQYAwDhQIEnQIIKDyFiEAEkSgBQrzAI-P7koEwYn4UkM3xnYA+DDNAiAigadEEwJIqKRGoYATCDnzPTFd5IFBwAAaam5OF59VhL20AHodQhkKgVcJ8O5+No1vxNtsgi14EKObEMYTMD4hYTHW7xoSeF7Cf6xc0ne6A8K-aGA57jnAmG7AzE45zbaLCnBU8UI4SM5nswHc4F89m5QsFag0LgAEyqmoasjkO3UCtjPWl9CVtQAIkwHcqcA7PA72lb5YALNWeXU6w24CPmzrh7gx8Iuz2qv3V33EhuO0xBwuROP1ZOKHatHqY8BNhxjDA2DAIKJdfr953u731++t+-d+-gB2gA)