# Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite when prettifying union type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to prettify the output of a union type so that users of this API see `ACTION_1 | ACTION_2 | etc` as the type.

```
export type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R ? { [K in keyof R]: R[K] } : never;

export type ActionUnion<T> = Prettify<{
  [K in keyof T]: K extends `actions`
    ? keyof T[K] | ActionUnion<T[K]>
    : T[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
    ? ActionUnion<T[K]>
    : never;
}[keyof T]>;
```

For example, when I use this type as the parameter to the `transition` function below, I get the error in the title. Without prettifying the `ActionUnion` type, it works:

```
type Config = {
  actions?: Record<string, string>;
  states?: Record<string, Config>;
}

export function machine<T extends Config>(config: T) {
  return {
    transition,
  };

  function transition(action: ActionUnion<T>) {
    const actionStr = action; // <-- ERROR HERE
  }
}
```

Note that this is meaningfully different to [a similar recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76405795/type-instantiation-is-excessively-deep-and-possibly-infinite) because the `ActionUnion` uses a separate mechanism for recursion and therefore the accepted answer on that question will not work here.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta&ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKVgxgSwGaIA8AKgHxwC8cxcoMwAdgCYDOcODewUcASnAH44AbzgBtANLsGcANbBEEPHwC6ALj6SVcAL5wNDYADduAbgBQ50JFgJkqAIIBjXBAYBVBjjclyVDFi4BITC5nDiUhxyCkrU6nBSdIyscAAGAIYu3gwsqWHhgtGKysRacAA%20cM6uHl4%20pRIqpPnhGg3aScxsvMBO0EyELDBQHADmADRwAK4MsgwQAO4MzQWF1dme2SRaKwUGxmbmOmLyxXGkFlbg0PAc9FB4magAwm54OKMi%20Zk1LAIaPT6UAGQxGDAmcFBYwu%20SG6XofwBvX6g2GY0mr04HxhOks1hucDwMyybjgAFtMgALDjAEi0ED0LpwTHvUakAAUfSxozaAEovuFMDAplAZKFVsN0jkcDVxvkdJdwkSGCSZJLpTV2T9shp1m5NvVSPzxQUuUM4Nq3ABlYaUC2qizhXG4oA)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your `Config` is referencing itself in the `states` property. We can try to limit the depth if you know the maximum depth. Would that work?

Comment: Is this question meaningfully different from [your other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76405795/2887218)?  If so, could you [edit] this one to make the difference very clear (e.g., explicitly link to the previous question and indicate why an answer to this question would not suffice for the other or vice versa).  Otherwise one of them is likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @wonderflame Limiting the depth would be fine. As long as it will still work with something like a depth of 7-10.

Comment: @jcalz yes it is different because the structure of the recursion type is different, so the accepted answer to the other question will not work. I will edit here.

Comment:  What "accepted answer to the other question"?  I don't see an answer posted there.  If you mean the comments, those aren't answers... and I have a suggestion there for a depth limiter, which would work here as well.  So what should we do?

Comment: You're right - I thought that had been written up and accepted. Well I'm happy with a depth limiter solution here, and over at the other link. They're both good solutions to my issue.

Comment: Okay, so could you explain to me in what way this question is not a duplicate of the other?  If I use my depth limiter solution from there over here I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wXrEDm).  I don't know how to proceed, but I certainly don't want to start writing up an answer to a question that gets closed as a duplicate while I'm doing so.  How do we proceed here?

Comment: If the depth limiter solution does work on both, then I suppose it's a duplicate. If you write it up over on the other link, I will close this myself.

Comment: Okay I'll head over that way now

Answer (score 0):

Try this prettify-type: `type Prettify<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] } & {};`

Comment: This causes playground (and the TS server in my IDE) to crash.

Comment: What version do you use? For me its working in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=31&pln=21&pc=42#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThYwCWAzEAeAKgPigXigG8oBtAaQhCmQDsoBrKge1SiwF0AudiqjqAF8oAMmKCA3ACgpoSFACCAYxTNaAVVrI12PIXiIU6DESlQy5GvSYhW7blEsQAHsAi0AJgGcoAAwCGKtq0Xr5m5lAA-IwsbFgUAgA+ikFqmsHYCTjh5jzx5AIubp4+AEoQSsxwHhhewHB0AOYANFAArrQMtMwA7rTZEVEpqhpaOvkcAxE8tBAAbhBw0oKkNnacONKy4NAAwmqoyI0ExOGBI16RPOWV1bX1Ta11DbSNm+F1-m6X1xVVNc9HlB9rRDm9ljJUB1UvQALaBAAWdAg2CgRXc3mBByOOAAFJVQUc8gBKU7mBDANpweimQb1fwhZAjZrhSQycxQ2gwqD0xkjXHnYI8ZQjdLjHCk2kRAl1KCCtQAZXqJ3ltAkUAA9BqoBgALS6qAAUVKpQA8qUoAAJY2G1lSQRAA

Comment: Clicking your link, I just get this loading tag: https://imgur.com/xzZBtyq and then the browser crashes.